# Arduino's string.toCharArray. Why do I get invalid conversion warning?

Tags: c++, string, arduino

I am trying to convert an Arduino string to an `uint8_t` array by using the `.toCharArray()` function of the Arduino String library.

This is the function where the warning occurs:

```
void sendData(String string) {
  uint8_t buf[string.length()];
  string.toCharArray(buf, string.length());
  rf69.send(buf, sizeof(buf));
}
```

And this is the error:

```
C:\Users\XX\Documents\Arduino\Transmitter\Transmitter.ino: In function 'int toInt(String)':
C:\Users\XX\Documents\Arduino\Transmitter\Transmitter.ino:42:40: warning: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
 string.toCharArray(buf, sizeof(buf));
                                    ^
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:231:0,
             from sketch\Transmitter.ino.cpp:1:
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/WString.h:161:7: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void String::toCharArray(char*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const'
void toCharArray(char *buf, unsigned int bufsize, unsigned int index=0) const
```

The strange thing about it is that it has already worked like this, without any error or warning.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong here?

Comment: You will probably need to explicitly cast from unsigned char * to char *.

Comment: use `char buf[string.length()];`

Comment: the problem is that rf69.send() needs uint8_t. And i dont understand why it already worked without warning..